# Google Maps Script Error https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/35/3/intl/en_gb/map.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps Platform API has been working fine for months, but now when the standard JavaScript file is invoked with my API Key:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...">
</script>
```

It produces popup error message:

```
Script Error
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/35/3/intl/en_gb/map.js
```

Other people I know are experiencing the same error.
The error arises in Internet Explorer but in Firefox the Map is simply not displayed.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any answers?

Comment: It is most likely an issue with either your code or the latest release of the "weekly" version of the API.  Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the error.

Answer (score 0):

After some diagnostic investigation I found the problem is associated with the **Map** class as used in:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{...});
```

My earlier scripts used a variable **Map** on the left instead of **map** and worked OK until recently:

```
Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{...});
```

Now it seems to conflict with the **Map** class, but by using the variable **Pane** instead it is working again:

```
Pane = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{...});
```

So it seems the variable can be anything except **Map**.